# Program in front of the start menu - DELPHI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Good morning ... I'm making a program that has to stand in front of everything in Windows ... From TASKBAR ... And even the Start Menu in Windows 8 ...
Maybe the question becomes confusing due to the translation ...

I am using the following code :

```
/ / TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND
  Self.TransparentColor : = True ;
  Self.TransparentColorValue : = ColorToRGB ( Self.Color );
/ / Brush.Style : = bsClear ;

/ / LEAVE IN FRONT OF ALL
Form1.BorderStyle : = bsNone ;
Form1.BorderIcons : = BorderIcons - [ biMaximize ] ;
Form1.WindowState : = wsNormal ;
Form1.Top : = 0 ;
Form1.Left : = 0;
Form1.Height : = Screen.Height ;
Form1.Width : = Screen.Width ;
Form1.FormStyle : = fsStayOnTop ;
```

1st problem: It starts in front of all windows and even TASKBAR ... but the problem arises because the background is transparent, therefore when I click , the program that is behind comes forward ....

2nd Problem: When I click with the right mouse button in some other program , the tab menu that appears in front of the program is ...

3rd Problem: The Windows Start menu is in front of the program , even the windows 8 ...

How can the program stay ahead of everything ... because I call him by voice command , then he must always appear in front ...

ATT JJ

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible. Delphi cannot target WinRT and the Windows 8 start screen runs in WinRT. To have any hope of achieving your stated goal you must use a tool that can target WinRT.